Does Bertini's theorem makes the codimension bigger?
The question comes from Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, II, exercise 8.4 (Complete Intersections in $P^n$).

(d) Suppose given integers $d_1, \dots, d_r \geq 1$, with $r < n$. Use Bertini's theorem to show that there exist nonsingular hypersurfaces $H_1, \dots, H_r$ in $P^n$, with $\operatorname{deg} H_i = d_i$, such that the scheme $Y = H_1 \cap\dots\cap H_r $ is irreducible and nonsingular of codimension $r$ in $P^n$.

With Bertini's theorem, I can find those nonsingular hypersurfaces $H_i$ and $Y = H_1 \cap\dots\cap H_r $. But how can I tell that $\operatorname{codim} Y = r$? Generally, the intersection of $r$ hypersurfaces may not have $\operatorname{codim}  = r$.
A complete solution of this exercise is appreciated.

Hint: As long as you have a variety $X$ which is positive-dimensional, there are only two cases for $\dim X\cap H$ for $H$ a hypersurface. What are they and how do they happen?

If $X$ is a closed variety, then Bertini's Theorem finds an $H$ such that $X$ is not in $H$. Since $H \cap X$ is a proper closed subset of $X$, we have $\operatorname{dim}H \cap  X < \operatorname{dim} X$ and $\operatorname{codim}H \cap  X > \operatorname{codim} X$. But adding one element to an ideal can makes the height grow at most by 1. So $\operatorname{codim}H \cap  X = \operatorname{codim} X + 1$. Also the regularity guarantees that $H \cap  X$ is irreducible (like Hartshorne's example 8.20.2). So we can continue. @KReiser, is this right?

Yep. ${}{}{}{}$

Since $n = 1$ is trivial for this exercise, assume $n > 1$.
Bertini's theorem gives $H_1$, a nonsingular hypersurface with $\deg H_1 = d_1$. Then Bertini's theorem gives $H_2$, and $H_1$ is not in $H_2$. Since $H_1 \cap H_2$ is a proper closed variety of $H_1$, and adding one element to an ideal can makes the height grow at most by 1, we deduce $\dim H_1 \cap H_2 = n-2$ and $\operatorname{codim} H_1 \cap H_2 = 2$. The regularity guarantees that $H_1 \cap H_2$ is irreducible (see Hartshorne's example 8.20.2).
So we can continue the above process and obtain $Y = H_1 \cap \dots \cap H_r$ as required.
